# spark dataframe or spark sql query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need advice on how to get future 3 incidents for each event , please see the below input and outputs.

**input:**

```
+-------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|eventId|incId|           eventDate|             incDate|
+-------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|      1|  123|2018-02-09 10:01:...|2018-02-09 10:02:...|
|      2|    0|2018-02-09 10:02:...|                null|
|      3|  124|2018-02-09 10:03:...|2018-02-09 10:03:...|
|      4|    0|2018-02-09 10:04:...|                null|
|      5|  125|2018-02-09 10:05:...|2018-02-10 11:03:...|
|      6|    0|2018-02-09 10:06:...|                null|
|      7|  126|2018-02-09 10:07:...|2018-02-10 11:04:...|
|      8|  127|2018-02-09 10:08:...|2018-02-10 09:05:...|
|      9|    0|2018-02-09 10:09:...|                null|
|     10|    0|2018-02-10 11:30:...|                null|
|     11|    0|2018-02-10 11:40:...|                null|
+-------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

*input can be created from*

```
val df=sc.parallelize( 
 |    Seq((1,123,"2/9/2018 10:01:00","2/9/2018 10:02:00"),
 |        (2,0,"2/9/2018 10:02:00",""),
 |        (3,124,"2/9/2018 10:03:00","2/9/2018 10:03:00"),
 |        (4,0,"2/9/2018 10:04:00",""),
 |        (5,125,"2/9/2018 10:05:00","2/10/2018 11:03:00"),
 |        (6,0,"2/9/2018 10:06:00",""),
 |        (7,126,"2/9/2018 10:07:00","2/10/2018 11:04:00"),
 |        (8,127,"2/9/2018 10:08:00","2/10/2018 09:05:00"),
 |        (9,0,"2/9/2018 10:09:00",""),
 |        (10,0,"2/10/2018 11:30:00",""),
 |        (11,0,"2/10/2018 11:40:00","")
 |         )).toDF("eventId","incId","eventDate1","incDate1").withColumn("eventDate", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("eventDate1"),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).cast("timestamp")).withColumn("incDate", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("incDate1"),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).cast("timestamp")).drop("eventDate1","incDate1")
```

**output expected:**

```
+-------+--------------------+-----+--------------------+----+----+----+
|eventId|           eventDate|incId|             incDate|inc1|inc2|inc3|
+-------+--------------------+-----+--------------------+----+----+----+
|      1|2018-02-09 10:01:...|  123|2018-02-09 10:02:...| 124| 127| 125|
|      2|2018-02-09 10:02:...|    0|                null| 124| 127| 125|
|      3|2018-02-09 10:03:...|  124|2018-02-09 10:03:...| 127| 125| 126|
|      4|2018-02-09 10:04:...|    0|                null| 125| 126|null|
|      5|2018-02-09 10:05:...|  125|2018-02-10 11:03:...| 125| 126|null|
|      6|2018-02-09 10:06:...|    0|                null| 125| 126|null|
|      7|2018-02-09 10:07:...|  126|2018-02-10 11:04:...| 125| 126|null|
|      8|2018-02-09 10:08:...|  127|2018-02-10 09:05:...| 125| 126|null|
|      9|2018-02-09 10:09:...|    0|                null| 125| 126|null|
+-------+--------------------+-----+--------------------+----+----+----+
```

*explanation on how to get output*

that means , get the next 3 incId's  for each  eventId(eventDate < IncDate).
PS:I have tried Window.partitionBy etc, but could not get any proper results.

Comment: please share your tryings too.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out something, but it is a cross join, and for large data sets I don't think this is would work, but if anybody has better ideas , please respond

**Answer**

```
val w= Window.orderBy(col("eventDate"))
val df2=df.filter(col("incId").notEqual("0")).toDF("eventId_1", "incId_1", "eventDate_1", "incDate_1")
val df3=df1.crossJoin(df2)
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w2=Window.partitionBy(col("eventId")).orderBy("incDate_1")


val df4=df3.where(col("eventDate").cast("long") <= col("incDate_1").cast("long") ).withColumn("inc1",lead(col("incId_1"),1).over(w2)).withColumn("inc2",lead(col("incId_1"),2).over(w2)).withColumn("inc3",lead(col("incId_1"),3).over(w2)).withColumn("incDate1",lead(col("incDate_1"),1).over(w2)).withColumn("incDate2",lead(col("incDate_1"),2).over(w2)).withColumn("incDate3",lead(col("incDate_1"),3).over(w2))

  val w3=Window.partitionBy(col("eventId")).orderBy("incDate_1")

  val df5=df4.withColumn("rn",row_number.over(w3)).where(col("rn")===1).select("eventId","eventDate","incId","incDate", "inc1", "inc2", "inc3", "incDate1","incDate2", "incDate3").orderBy("eventId").show
```